# I need to write a query that will return specific values from an empty table

Tags: sql, oracle

So I need to write a query that will return a single row of data consisting of 4 columns using an empty table. I also need to specify the names of the columns that will be returned.
I can't use the following words in the query: insert, update, delete, drop, create, union, minus, intersect, order by.

So for example the query could return:

> |Course | Status | Semester | Year|
>
> |Math   | (null) | s1       | 2013|

I'm not sure how else to describe what I'm after, so let me know if you need more details.

Comment: If table is empty then how will you get values Math | (null) | s1 | 2013| ?

Comment: The following would work in SQL Server, I don't know about Oracle: `SELECT 'Math' AS Course, NULL AS Status, 's1' AS Semester, '2013' AS Year;`

Comment: What happened to the homework tag? I went to go edit the question and it's unavailable... and let's be honest, this definitely fits the bill as far as a homework question.

Comment: @m-y The homework tag has been permanently [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) and removed.

Comment: @ean5533: So... we just vote to close now? geez.

Comment: OK. You need to do that? You have our permission. Go ahead and get started. We'll wait until you post your effort to write that query... Still here... Let us know when you're done.....

Comment: @m-y:  If this question - regardless of it being homework or not - can't stand on its own two legs without the tag, it's not a good question for the site.

Answer (score 2):

Do some reading on [`SELECT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm) and [Selecting from the DUAL Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/queries009.htm)

```
SELECT 'math' course 
       ,NULL  status
       ,'s1'  semester
       ,2013  year 
  FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
| COURSE | STATUS | SEMESTER | YEAR |
-------------------------------------
|   math | (null) |       s1 | 2013 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11438)**

*Since you return only constant values you can use whatever table name you want (not only `dual`) if it exists in your schema. But `dual` exists in Oracle specifically for such needs.*

Answer (score 2):

When you need a single row result in Oracle, you can use a special table called `dual`.  This has one row in it, so you get one row back.  Note that in the select below we are not fetching any actual values from `dual`, it's just used to give us one row and we select constants.

```
SELECT 'Math' AS Course, 
       NULL AS Status, 
       's1' AS Semester, 
       '2013' AS Year
FROM DUAL;
```

(Aside: This seems like a strange question - the empty table does not help here.  Or did you mean, *only* when the table is empty?)